# I want to use a Javascript function in a css property

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a simple game using Javascript, Css and Html. And i created a javascript function that **generate random number from 3 to 15 then it add an 's' to make the result like (15s) to use it like an animation-duration in css.**

I've google it but i didn't find the sample.

**Js Code :**

```
function rand() {
   var min=3; 
   var max=15;  
   var random = Math.random() * (+max - +min) + +min;
   var time = random+'s';
   return time;
}
```

**Css code:**

```
.enemy {
 position: relative;
 right:300px;
 animation-name:move;
 animation-duration:(the rand() function here);
}
```

Comment: https://gomakethings.com/two-ways-to-set-an-elements-css-with-vanilla-javascript/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE once supported CSS expressions, but they were deprecated long ago and not supported by other browsers. You can set the value via JS like this:

```js
document.querySelector('.enemy').style.animationDuration = rand() + 's';
```

Of course, you'll have to do this every time the content changes (i.e. when adding an element with the enemy class), you'll probably want to do this for all possible elements using `querySelectorAll()` instead and iterating over them, handle the case when no such element exists (thus returning `null`) etc.

A short example based on https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation3

```js
function rand() {
   var min=3; 
   var max=15;  
   var random = Math.random() * (+max - +min) + +min;
   var time = random+'s';
   return time;
}
var randomDuration = rand();
console.log('animation duration: ' + randomDuration);
document.querySelector('.enemy').style.animationDuration = randomDuration;
```

```css
.enemy {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-name: example;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
  0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
  25%  {background-color:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
  50%  {background-color:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
  75%  {background-color:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
  100% {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
  0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
  25%  {background-color:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
  50%  {background-color:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
  75%  {background-color:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
  100% {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="enemy"></div>
```

Comment: What should i write in the animation-duration field in css ? because nothing happend when i write this js code.

Comment: You could either put a default value in there or just leave it out completely. I'll try and create a short working example.

Comment: I added an example snippet. I overlooked that your `rand()` function already returns an `s` after the value, so that might have been the catch.

Comment: You're welcome, please feel free to mark my answer as accepted. Another side note: You might want to add `Math.round()` (or `.toFixed()`) into your function. Modern browsers supporting CSS animation shouldn't have a problem with that many decimal places, but you could add it just to prevent any surprises.

Comment: Thank you, But my code won't start, i followed step by step the instruments but nothing happened.

Comment: Well, the example I provided is clearly working, so without seeing the rest of your code, it's impossible to tell what's going on.

Comment: @keyframes move {
  0% {
    position: relative;
    right:300px;
}
  50% {
    position: relative;
    right:-1500px;
}
  100% {
    position: relative;
    right:300px;
}
}

.enemy {
  position: relative;
  right:300px;
  animation-name:move;
  
}

Comment: function rand() {
   var min=3; 
   var max=4;  
   var random = Math.random() * (+max - +min) + +min;
   var time = random+'s';
   return time;
}
var randomDuration = rand();
alert('animation duration: ' + randomDuration);
document.querySelector('.enemy').style.animationDuration = randomDuration;

Comment: Please provide that as a fully working minimal code example including HTML, CSS and JS demonstrating your problem, instead of in the comments here.

Comment: that's help you?